# Different alpha in arrows using quiver on top of rectangle

Tags: python, matplotlib, alpha-transparency

I have a Rectangle plotted with matplotlib with alpha=0.8 . I can plot a marker with different alpha on it but when i try to set the alpha parameter on the arrows of quiver it seems like it doesn't change. I was wondering if there is a way to set a larger amount of transparency for the arrows without changing the transparency of the Rectangle.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figure=plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))  
ax=plt.gca()
plt.xticks(np.arange(-20,20,1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-20,20,1))
rect=plt.Rectangle((1,1),10,10,facecolor='#32CD32',alpha=0.8)
ax.plot(2,2,marker='o',alpha=1,color='red')
ax.quiver( 2,2, 2,2, color='black', scale_units='inches', scale=10,width=0.0015,headlength=5,headwidth=3,alpha=1)
ax.add_patch(rect)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

That's the plot I am getting. I want the arrow to be dark blue without changing the alpha of the green above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quiver alpha is working as expected. The problem is with the `zorder` of the objects you are drawing. The rectangle is being drawn over the arrow but beneath the red dot:

```
import numpy as np               # v 1.19.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # v 3.3.2

figure=plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))  
ax=plt.gca()
plt.xticks(np.arange(-20,20,1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-20,20,1))
rect=plt.Rectangle((1,1),10,10,facecolor='#32CD32',alpha=0.8)
ax.plot(2,2,marker='o',alpha=1,color='red')
ax.quiver( 2,2, 20,20, color='black', scale_units='inches', scale=10, width=0.015,
          headlength=5,headwidth=3,alpha=1)
ax.add_patch(rect)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: problem]

This can be solved by setting the `zorder` parameter in each object so that the arrow is drawn over the rectangle:

```
figure=plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))  
ax=plt.gca()
plt.xticks(np.arange(-20,20,1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-20,20,1))
rect=plt.Rectangle((1,1),10,10,facecolor='#32CD32',alpha=0.8,zorder=1)
ax.plot(2,2,marker='o',alpha=1,color='red')
ax.quiver( 2,2, 20,20, color='black', scale_units='inches', scale=10, width=0.015,
          headlength=5,headwidth=3,alpha=1,zorder=2)
ax.add_patch(rect)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: solution]

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the issue i had. I didn't know that you could set the drawing order of artists. That is determined by the zorder attribute as you said.